# Z-Index Not Working - Alternative Technique or Fix

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have assigned a fixed positioned menubar a high z-index, yet it still appears below other elements on my website. Is there an alternative technique I could use or something wrong with the code I have written. My website with the issue is [here](http://ninjawarrior.info/new/) (note: you need to scroll up after scrolling down for the navbar to appear). The menu bar that is not appearing properly has the following code

```
#headerfull {
position:absolute;
top:-100px;
left:0;
z-index:10000;
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:#000000;
opacity:.7;
display:none;   
}
```

but, for some reason, the z-index does not work. Elements like the "NinjaWarrior.info" image in the front and center, with a lower z-index appears in front of the navbar. The code for that image is below

```
<img style="position:absolute;z-index:10" src="images/logo_main.png" width="900" height="300" alt="American Ninja Warrior Fan Site">
```

Comment: Recommended read: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: They are in different stacking contexts, you can't use z-index on them.

Comment: @CBroe Does the fact that I used an opacity of .7 on the navbar account for the issue?

Comment: Z-Index is a lot more complex than just being above the a certain level. Think it as books stacked on top of each other. Just because it is the first page in a book doesnt mean it is the first page in all of the books.

Comment: You should move the dockable header menu to a child of body. Same level as the sidebar and the rest of the main containers. Show it when you need to and hide it when not in use

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this css:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

`z-index` works on containers with the same stacking context.

In your code, the `DIV`s `header` and `content` are siblings, and that's a condition for `z-index` numbers to apply.

The most easy way of memorizing this rule is by "code versioning":

```
<DIV with z-index=1>
    <DIV with z-index=3/>   
</DIV>
<DIV with z-index=2>
```

So, like decimals, or versioning number, `1.3` will **never** be greater than `2`, and therefore the inner DIV will be always rendered below the second outer DIV.

Other than that, you **need** to apply `positioning` to each DIV which sets `z-index`.

I just set a big number because I was lazy, you can find a good feasible number by yourself if you want =), but this code works as I tested it on your website.

Thank you.

Be sure to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: This is true, and it works. Not sure why this was downvoted. Any comments?

Comment: I think it's because of my promptly `10000` =)

Comment: yeah, it worked. I'm not sure why there were downvotes

Comment: Most likely because the menu itself needs to be hovered to appear so when the downvoters inspected and tried it without hovering. The menu did not show so they thought it does not work. But anyone who knows how z-index work should know this would work when they inspected

Comment: Good memory rule there!

Answer (score -3):

z-index is not working for me on child elements because of width and height which is declared ,I started  adding **{display :Inline}** on my parent div on hover of child div.