# google ads displaying in front of everything despite z-index

Tags: css, adsense

I have a website with some google ad banners and trying to use an overlay for a login form but some (not all) banner ads are displaying in front of the overlay.

I did some googling and found that those ads display at a z-index of 100000 or something like that.

I set the z-index of every portion of my overlay to 9999999999999 and still the ad appears in front.

A picture of the problem is here: http://www.freemicsnyc.com/Freemics_v2.3/problem.jpg

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you maybe show some code? Or perhaps link to the site in which you are trying to accomplish this?

Comment: This should help you resolve the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250846/z-index-not-working-alternative-technique-or-fix

Answer (score 0):

I've found doing something similar to this fixes the problem.

```
<style>
#aswift_0_expand {
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the element where you are injecting google ad, into parent div that has position relative and set z-index into 1, if you'd set z-index into negative number whole ad would become unclickable so it makes zero sense

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1">
  <ins class="adsbygoogle".../>
</div>
```

then your fixed clickable element which can be floating at the point of viewport where google ad is displayed should have bigger z-index than ad wrapper and it's fixed

```
<div class="fixed" onclick="clickEvent()"/>
<style>
  .fixed {
    display: block;
    height: 5rem;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50vh;
    width: 2.5rem;
    z-index: 50;
  }
</style>
```